# Are Python class destructors guaranteed to execute before the program ends?

Tags: python

We can force to execute a destructor with `del`, and usually just let the garbage collector do its work, but if we define a class destructor in Python, is it guaranteed to execute for every object instantiated?

Comment: No... https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__ `It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.`

Comment: `del` does not call an object's `__del__` method btw, it just decrements it's reference count

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Coming from C++ I've used to use classes and construction/destruction for RAII, that's a bit different!

Comment: No worries, I would not rely on `__del__` if you can because of this reason. If you need to perform some cleanup context managers are probably the most suitable Python construct

Comment: Using `del` doesn't necessarily help; if an exception is raised, all the local variables are attached to the traceback (for the use of debugging tools) so the objects won't be collected as long as that exception continues to exist, which may be well outside the scope of your function. In the interactive interpreter, unhandled exceptions are placed in a global variable, so it won't be cleared until the *next* time there's an unhandled exception. In various corner cases (which are considered an implementation detail, not part of the language spec), `__del__` is not run at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: `__del__` is not really a destructor in the C++ sense and you probably don't want to use it.

Instead, if you need cleanup, you should probably make the objects into context managers (by writing `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods) and use them in the `with` statement, and/or give them `close` methods which need to be called explicitly. Most classes in Python and widely-used libraries that need to release external resources do both (often by having `__enter__` return `self` and `__exit__` call `self.close()`).

With the garbage collection, there is usually no need to deallocate any memory allocated in `__init__` or `__new__`, as might be done in C++, since it will be collected automatically.

There are uses for the `__del__` method, but they're rare.

Comment: The CPython interpreter very rarely frees memory, even when an object is garbage collected

Comment: Thanks, that actually answered my follow up question too :)